# Deleted ~/.Skype but chat history persists

Tags: 14.04, skype

The title says it all; I deleted the `~/.Skype` dir, restarted Skype, agreed to the T&Cs and added my sign-in information, yet my chat history still remains whenever I click any contact I have spoken with.

How do I remove chat history?

Comment: It is stored on skype's servers. You probably can't remove it, and certainly not locally.

Comment: @RegisteredUser well, if you read the answers to that question you can see that every one of them advocates deleting the `~/.Skype` dir as a solution (in fact I think that is where I got the idea in the first place). This does not work for me and that is the subject of this question; thus, I would I argue it is not a duplicate if as @Tim suggests the history is really stored on Skype's servers and is not removable.